# Set a value to a key with ttl

Tags: redis

Is it possible to setnx a key with a value and a ttl in single command in redis

I am trying to implement locking in redis and http://redis.io/commands/hsetnx seems like the best way to do that. It is atomic and returns 0 if a key is already present. Is it possible to HSETNX with TTL

e.g.

```
HSETNX myhash mykey "myvalue" 10

#and key expires after 10 seconds, and a subsequent HSETNX after 10 seconds returns a value 1 i.e. it behaves as if mykey is not present in myhash
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that Redis have no support for fields expiration in hashmaps.

You can only expire the entire hashmap by calling `EXPIRE` on `myhash`.

So, you should reconsider using ordinary Redis strings instead of hashmaps, because they support [`SETEX` operation](http://redis.io/commands/setex).

It'll work fine unless you want to take advantage of using `HGETALL`, `HKEYS` or `HVALS` on your hashmap `myhash`:

```
SETEX mynamespace:mykey 10 "myvalue"
```

`mynamespace` is not a hashmap here, it simply a prefix, but in most cases it works just as hashmaps do. The only difference is that there is no efficient way to tell which keys are stored in the given `namespace` or to get them all with a single command.

Comment: Yea I just noticed SETEX too. But other good thing with SETNX is it returns false if a key is present. I don't think SETEX does that..